# Spring JPA Crud Repository findAll() performacne improvement

Tags: postgresql, performance, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

In my project i store high number of rows(~300mln records) in one table in postgres database. One row contains 77 columns with String, Integer types few booleans and dates. My issue is that when im trying to browse records on GUI it works extremly slow even if my DB contains only 3% of its final capacity.

For DB connection im using Spring JPA, and findAll() method with pagination, 20 records per page takes almost 3.5s (after adding indexes, before it was 7,5sec), when i have ~10mln records in DB(3.3GB).
If i do same type of query from pgsql cli

`slelect * from myTable order by column1 limit 20;`

I get same result set immediately, so it is not issue with postgres performance.
Overriding defautl implementation of findAll() with native query reduced time to about 2,8s which is still to long, i also treid with fetching few comuns only using view containing 6 out of 77 columns, but it didn't change much.

Any suggestion where to look or how can i improve performance that this app will be still usable with database containing 30 times more records?

P.S. App is nothing more than GUI for browsing these records, in addition every 15minutes ~50K of new records is being inserted. My VM have assigned 8 vCPU and 12GB of RAM.

Comment: I usually deal with similar tables and 3 seconds for a paginated call is not normal. You will have to share some code and the table DDL(indexes included) if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what is causing this delay, it is the `count()` method. With mocked count this `findAll()` takes aboud 300ms for first query, all subsequent queries take like 12-20ms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).